# How to benchmark fmt::format API on https://quick-bench.com

Tags: c++, benchmarking, fmt

I am trying to understand and benchmark fmt::format API ( https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html ). I  wrote a simple test in compiler explorer i.e, https://godbolt.org/z/fMcf3nczE.

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <fmt/core.h>

static void BM_format(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Perform setup here
  for (auto _ : state) 
  {
      std::string s = fmt::format( "{}", "testing fmt::format in benchmark");
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(BM_format);
// Run the benchmark
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Then, I launched quick-bench from compile explorer.
In quick-bench, it gives an error as

> Error or timeout bench-file.cpp:2:10: fatal error: fmt/core.h: No such
> file or directory
> 2 | #include <fmt/core.h>
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.

Is the c++ fmt library supported in quick-bench so that it compiles and executes? if not, any alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, quick-bench does not support external libraries which require separate compilation ([as fmt does](https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html#building-the-library)). As a side note, it does [not support the inclusion of header-only libraries via URLs, either](https://github.com/FredTingaud/quick-bench-back-end/issues/20#issue-931395082).

I would have said that in this specific case you could use C++20 `std::format` instead, if you are not tied to fmt lib specifically. But unfortunately, neither clang 14 nor gcc 11 (or rather, libc++ and libstdc++) have implemented it yet.

So I fear what you ask is simply impossible right now. You need to benchmark on your own computer.